# combinatory question....

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

Any idea for this question:
Let $ 0<i<\delta n$ where $0<\delta \le 1-q^{-1}$ and $ q\ge 2$. prove that $ n\choose {i-1}$  $\times (q-1)^{i-1} <$$   n \choose i$$(q-1)^i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that proving
$$\dbinom{n}{i-1} (q-1)^{i-1} < \dbinom{n}i (q-1)^i$$
is equivalent to proving
$$\dfrac{n!}{(i-1)!(n+1-i)!} < \dfrac{n!}{(n-i)!i!} (q-1)$$
which is equivalent to proving

$$\begin{align*}
\dfrac{i}{n+1-i} <(q-1) &\iff \dfrac{n+1}{n+1-i} <q\\
&\iff (n+1-i) > \dfrac{n+1}q\\
&\iff i<(n+1)\dfrac{q-1}q
\end{align*}$$

Now you should be able to conclude what you want.

Comment: Thanks .. now its clear to me .